# Pow inside Python function

Tags: python

Edit: this was a stupid mistake and probably won't help you find an answer to your problem...
I was jung and just started learning to code

I know that I can use num ** pow as an alternative but just to for the future I want to understand why the following code does not work:

```
def math(num, pow):
    return pow(int(num), int(pow))
    # the return keyword returns the result
    pass


print(math(2, 4))
```

Comment: why is your variable named the same way as the built-in function?

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you write "does not work"?

Answer (score 1):

You are redefining the the name of the symbol.
`pow` in your function `math` is the variable passed as an argument, not a function.

Then `math` is the name of a module, you shouldn't redefine it; call the function in another way

Answer (score 1):

you are shadowing the built-in function `pow` with the local variable `pow`, you can see that you have as your function argument `pow`

you can use:

```
__builtin__.pow(int(num), int(pow))
```